# C# Regex that both captures or excludes the content of a line if it contains certain characters

Tags: c#, html, regex, testing

I've been trying to build a Regex that analyze's the content of multiples HTML pages and check if they have any Accented letters like "á à â ã".
The pattern should capture the whole line of code if it detect's any accented letters AND ignore those in comments.

Here's an example:

```
<li><a href="#prepaid-plan" data-toggle="tab">I want to capture this á</a </li> 
//I don't want to capture this á
```

The example above should capture only:

```
<li><a href="#prepaid-plan" data-toggle="tab">I want to capture this á</a </li>
```

I've made this pattern so far:

```
(\W(?<!\/\/)(?=\w*[á|â|ã|à|é|ê|è|í|î|ì|ó|ô|õ|ò|ú|û|ù])\S*)
```

But it fails when the word with the accented letter is not what immediatly follows the "//" and only capture the word, not the entire line.

Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance!

--------------ANSWER-------------

The Regex I used was a mix of the comments and the correct answer I marked.

```
([\n]|^)(?<Value>(?! *\/\/| *@\*| *\/\*| *<!--| *\\\*)([^\n]*?)[áâãàéêèíîìóôõòúûù](((?! *\/\/| *@\*| *\/\*| *<!--| *\\\*).)*))
```

This Regex will capture the whole line if it has a accented letter, ignore comments (@*  //  *  /*  <--!) even if they have spaces behind them.

Thanks again to the people that commented and answered.

Comment: What about other types of comments? i.e. /* */ and <!-- -->

Comment: You only need pipes when you are using capture groups, e.g. `(a|b|c)`. Square braces are only one character regardless, e.g. `[áâãàéêèíîìóôõòúûù]`. The way you have it now matches a literal `|`

Comment: @Marie thanks for correcting me, good to know that square braces do that!

Comment: @itsme86 havent thought about that, I'll implement it for sure, ty man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```
([\n]|^)(?!\/\/)([^\n]*?)[á|â|ã|à|é|ê|è|í|î|ì|ó|ô|õ|ò|ú|û|ù](((?!\/\/).)*)
```

or with the designated group

```
([\n]|^)(?<Value>(?!\/\/)([^\n]*?)[á|â|ã|à|é|ê|è|í|î|ì|ó|ô|õ|ò|ú|û|ù](((?!\/\/).)*))
```

and take the Value group value.